# A thought on Stack Overflow version confusion in Q/A

Tags: feature-request, language-versions

Several Stack Overflow Q/A posts already have answers (but not questions, unfortunately, nearly as often) stratified by version number. Sometimes answers are easily convertible to satisfy your framework version, but often, solutions require deprecated libraries/functions to work. You typically have to look into the comments section to find out if someone's debunked a particular answer for your version, or you have to consider the arduous task of rolling back (SDK, dependencies, what-have-you) in order to make "it" work.

A simple fix could be requiring version tags in the question and answer, but I imagine a more sophisticated feature that doesn't end up being the extreme (the equivalent of documentation for each API/release/SDK version).

SO is a solutions-focused community, which is its major edge over documentation, which serves best as an instruction-set for tools. Can you imagine SO as the first (if not only) stop to solving a problem particular to your framework version?

Answer (score 13):

If there's a new version of a framework/API/SDK then there's nothing stopping you adding a new answer using that version.

That's what makes Stack Overflow useful - there can be multiple answers offering different ways of solving a problem. You just pick the one that's right for you.

One word of warning though. It may be that the question is about a *specific* version of a framework/API/SDK because that's what the questioner has to work with. It might be a legacy system or one that has to run on an older OS. In this case adding an answer that uses the latest and greatest technology might not be useful.

Comment: Entirely agree. The purpose and community of SO is what brought that to fruition in the first place. If there wasn't a requirement for specifying version when contributing to Q/A, how can SO otherwise encourage people to do so on their own, *consistently*?

Comment: @AlleyOOP why would we want to encourage it? If it is absolutely necessary that they use a specific version then yes they should say that, but the better question is the one without version dependance.

Comment: @TinyGiant I can't tell if your question is rhetorical or not, because immediately following your question, you gave a reason as to why it is helpful to mention versioning in answers. I have a non-rhetorical question for you, why do you think that encouraging contributors to specify version (obviously, when necessary) will not improve how people experience the site?

Comment: @AlleyOOP if a specific version is required it would be nonsensical to not say that, and the vast majority of answers and questions that are version specific _already say that_. So what would be the point in encouraging _everyone_ regardless of whether their question or answer is version specific or not? The only thing I can see coming from it is for users who wouldn't normally add a version to add one unnecessarily, therefor artificially limiting the usefulness of their question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an old question that, in retrospect, is clearly specific to an older version, you should add a version-specific tag to that question. I think adding a sentence in the question referring to the version also would help future visitors.